# customize permission in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

i want to grant user update permission in Table 
and deny delete permission for this user.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this like a textbook question? There must be a manual page for that somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible natively. The Cassandra role-based permissions as shown [here](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/a-quick-tour-of-internal-authentication-and-authorization-security-in-datastax-enterprise-and-apache-cassandra/) show that granting a user MODIFY includes both UPDATE (which is effectively INSERT) and DELETE. You can't select which one you want.

Check out [this blog entry I found](http://devblog.michalski.im/2012/04/05/adding-simple-authentication-to-cassandra/), though and see if there's anything useful there. It looks like you could do read or write only permissions. Maybe if you can do write-only permissions you can limit the user from being able to delete a table or keyspace.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

-em

Comment: i have two DC one of them in EC2 and the other in local the local DC for archiving data  the DCin EC2 for 3 month only can disable delete from replication